# Receive all Messages on Java Server Over XMPP Server

Tags: spring, tomcat, xmpp, smack

I want to create a Java Server(Most Possibly Tomcat) which will listen to all the incoming messages of the XMPP Server. Right now I am Little bit confused and using Smack API library for the Server Side Implementation but it requires Login for each XMPPConnection.

Is There any way in which I can listen to all XMPP messages on my Java Server thru XMPP Protocol? Or is there any Library which can be used for Message listening on Server Side and I can Receive this Packets as Java Objects?

Technologies :

XMPP Server : OpenFire

Java Server : Tomcat

API or Library : Smack and Spring Integeration

Comment: How about an openfire plugin?

Comment: Yeah Sure! If that Openfire Plugin helps me to send the XMPP Messages on my Tomcat Server and then I am able to recieve all messages on my Tomcat Server via Some API or Library then It'll be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was able to perform the Java Server via Custom Java Design Pattern, i.e.

1) I opened up a channel using Spring Integration then used this XMPPConnection in my whole application (Autowiring obviously)

2) Then using Smack library I read all the packets received to the Admin user and took a Custom JSON with "from" and "to" and then just passed on the XMPP packet to the "to" user.

On the whole application level, I took the packets on the Admin end(Which is logged in on the server end) and then passed on the desired packets to "TO" user. By this I always received each packet on the Admin user end (which is opened on my Java server as a client)